# Flutter - Keep app running in the background even when app is closed with bluetooth service

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth

My project involves connecting to a Bluetooth device and reading constant data from the device.

I am using the plugin [FlutterBleLib](https://github.com/Polidea/FlutterBleLib) to connect to the Bluetooth device. The process of connecting to the device and reading data is working fine.

The issue I am having is when the user closes the app.

Found the following [article: The Tricky Task of Keeping Flutter Running](https://medium.com/stuart-engineering/keep-flutter-running-background-on-android-6ffc85be0234),  which allows us to run the code in the background even after the app is closed. The sample runs a counter service in the background. My idea was to replace the counter service with the Bluetooth service.

The sample code was built on pre 1.12 Android project. So, I upgraded the code to embedding version 2 using the following [resource](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects).

I was able to build the project and everything is working fine on the main UI, but as soon as the app is closed, the code is starting the FlutterNativeView and then when it is trying to start the bluetooth service it is failing with the following error:

```
I/flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SERVICES LIBRARY ╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    The following MissingPluginException was thrown while activating platform stream on channel
    flutter_ble_lib/stateRestoreEvents:
    MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method listen on channel
I/flutter: flutter_ble_lib/stateRestoreEvents)
    When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
    #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:159:7)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:12)
    #2      EventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:542:29)
    #3      EventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:528:64)
    #16     FlutterBleLib.restoredState (package:flutter_ble_lib/src/bridge/lib_core.dart:52:8)
    #17     InternalBleManager.createClient (package:flutter_ble_lib/src/internal_ble_manager.dart:23:15)
    #18     DevicesBloc.init (package:in_field/modules/eld_ble/devices_bloc.dart:54:10)
    #19     BluetoothService.startBluetoothService (package:in_field/modules/eld_ble/background/bluetooth_service.dart:60:18)
    #20     backgroundMain (package:in_field/modules/eld_ble/background/background_main.dart:11:22)
    #21     _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:233:25)
    #26     _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:225:5)
    #27     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:301:19)
    (elided 17 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl and dart:async)
    ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getState on channel flutter_ble_lib)
    #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:159:7)
    <asynchronous suspension>
    #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:12)
    #2      BluetoothStateMixin.state (package:flutter_ble_lib/src/bridge/bluetooth_state_mixin.dart:29:8)
    #3      BluetoothStateMixin.observeBluetoothState (package:flutter_ble_lib/src/bridge/bluetooth_state_mixin.dart:34:43)
    <asynchronous suspension>
```

The issue is happening as soon the FlutterNativeView had been started.

Here is the code from the sample before the upgrade (BackgroundService.kt):

```
private fun startFlutterNativeView() {
    Log.i("BackgroundService", "Starting FlutterNativeView")
    FlutterMain.ensureInitializationComplete(this, null)

    getCallbackInformation()?.let { flutterCallbackInformation ->
        flutterNativeView = FlutterNativeView(this, true).apply {
            GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(pluginRegistry)

            val args = FlutterRunArguments().apply {
                bundlePath = FlutterMain.findAppBundlePath()
                entrypoint = flutterCallbackInformation.callbackName
                libraryPath = flutterCallbackInformation.callbackLibraryPath
            }

            runFromBundle(args)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code after the upgrade:

```
 private fun startFlutterNativeView() {
    Log.i("BackgroundService", "Starting FlutterNativeView")
    FlutterMain.ensureInitializationComplete(this, null)

    getCallbackInformation()?.let { flutterCallbackInformation ->
        flutterNativeView = FlutterNativeView(this, true).apply {

            //GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(FlutterEngineCache.getInstance().get("test")!!)

            //GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith("com.polidea.flutter_ble_lib.FlutterBleLibPlugin");

            //FlutterBleLibPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("com.polidea.flutter_ble_lib.FlutterBleLibPlugin"))

            //FlutterBleLibPlugin.registerWith(registrarFor("com.polidea.flutter_ble_lib.FlutterBleLibPlugin"))

            //GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(FlutterEngine(applicationContext))


            val args = FlutterRunArguments().apply {
                bundlePath = FlutterMain.findAppBundlePath()
                entrypoint = flutterCallbackInformation.callbackName
                libraryPath = flutterCallbackInformation.callbackLibraryPath
            }

            runFromBundle(args)
        }
    }
}
```

The commented lines are the place where I am trying to register the Bluetooth plugin but it is failing with errors for all the above trials.

Can anyone tell me where I am doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure to include the error, as it might not be trivial to figure out what is outputting the error!

Comment: hi... first code snippet includes the error that I am receiving

Comment: Yeah you're right, even though it seems to be the plugin error rather than flutter. That is why I thought there would be other errors for your code specifically, shall I say. My bad!

Answer (score -1):

See [float button overlay](https://pub.dev/packages/float_button_overlay)

Register your background service above the `main` method,
and call `registerCallback()` inside the `main` method.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29214985)

Comment: @B001ᛦ: Without the link, this still offers a proposed answer. This is _not_ a link-only answer.